# how to get event triggered in a transaction 1 which is called in transaction 2 in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have 2 transactions, transaction A and transaction B. Each transactions having one event in them.

transaction A -- Event A
transaction B -- Event B

When I am calling transaction A inside/from the transaction B it is making all the changes defined in transaction A but there is no sign of any Event A in transaction history.
I know the fact that it will be only one transaction there will not be a separate transaction for transaction A but is there a way to get Event A? As it must be triggered.
Thanks

---

I am editing the question.
We can see the event A in transaction B.
No answer required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in the same business network? (also: shouldn't the title be changed to Hyperledger Composer (if you've tagged Composer?) If yes to 'same network', you cannot call one transaction from another in Composer. However, as commented on here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4375 a  transaction in Composer (as modeled in your model file)  can call other *functions* to allow for code modularisation, but it will only be registered as a **single** transaction request in the transaction registry. That transaction can be (for example) multiple smart contract updates from one or more transaction functions (if a, then update b and c, then update d and add e and emit events, as a unit of work), to update/add/delete from different asset or participant registries, as a unit of work.

On events: while you can issue an 'emit' at any point in your transaction logic, that event will not actually be emitted until the transaction is committed. However, throwing the error in the transaction, makes the transaction roll back - changes made by transactions are atomic, either the transaction is successful and all changes are applied, or the transaction fails and no changes are applied (same applies for event emission).

Comment: I have edited my question. Actually we can see the event A also in the transaction B. thanks for the answer